# How to change the selected Radio button dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, input, radio-button

Imagine I have a few rows of radio boxes, with 4 options each... 1, 2, 3 and a blank value.

```
<input name="addons_1[23]" type="radio" value="1" />
<input name="addons_1[23]" type="radio" value="2" />
<input name="addons_1[23]" type="radio" value="3" />
<input name="addons_1[23]" type="radio" value="" />

<input name="addons_1[32]" type="radio" value="1" />
<input name="addons_1[32]" type="radio" value="2" />
<input name="addons_1[32]" type="radio" value="3" />
<input name="addons_1[32]" type="radio" value="" />

<input name="addons_1[45]" type="radio" value="1" />
<input name="addons_1[45]" type="radio" value="2" />
<input name="addons_1[45]" type="radio" value="3" />
<input name="addons_1[45]" type="radio" value="" />

<input name="addons_1[46]" type="radio" value="1" />
<input name="addons_1[46]" type="radio" value="2" />
<input name="addons_1[46]" type="radio" value="3" />
<input name="addons_1[46]" type="radio" value="" />

<input name="addons_1_noneed" id="addons_1_noneed" type="checkbox" /><label for="addons_1_noneed">Addons not needed.</label>
```

In this case, I want to set it so that when the input checkbox at the end (id=addons_1_noneed) is checked ON, I would like to have the radioboxes (all of them) to ahve the 4th one checked (where value=""). And based on the code, I cannot change it to have a non-empty value.

So the function I have tried the following functions on the click function attached to #addons_1_noneed element:

```
$('#addons_1_noneed').click(function(){
   $("input[name='addons_1[]'] option[value='']").each(function({
      $(this).attr("selected","selected");
   });
});
```

Did not work.

```
$('#addons_1_noneed').click(function(){
   $("input[name='addons_1[]']").each(function({
      $(this).val('');
   });
});
```

Didn't work either.

What am I missing?

Comment: console.log($(this)), and go from there. Make sure the selector is valid.

Comment: Well... what did the console.log spit out?

Comment: I separated the onclick function out to a separate function of its own.. and now I'm having no luck whatsoever. The function runs, but then says function is "undefined" which makes absolutely no sense.. if the function has an error wouldn't it never even begin to run? I put alert("ME!"); at the beginning of the function before the selectors kick in to test if the function is being called. That runs fine. but the console logs do not happen.. WTF!!??

Comment: I'm an idiot... i forgot the addons_1[xx] array IDs were defined by the mysql IDs, so the selector I had was not working (addons_1_[]). Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, okay. Start simple. Comment out your click stuff for now. Let's make sure you are grabbing the right selector. var test = $("input[name='addons_1[]']"); console.log( test ); Open up your inspector in whatever browser your using, and inspect the object.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addons_1_noneed').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr('checked')=="checked"){
            $('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
        }else{
            $('input:radio').attr('checked', false);
        }

    });
});
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/bNcRn/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var notesStatusValue = '<c:out value="${tradeMarkWatchReportSearchDto.notesStatusValue}"/>' ;
        jq("input:radio[name=notes]").each(function(){
            if(jq(this).val() == notesStatusValue) {
                jq(this).attr('checked','checked');
            }
        });

<input type="radio" name="notes" id="notes" value="Y">
                    <spring:message code="tm.report.search.added" text="DEBUG: Added" />
                    <input type="radio" name="notes" id="notes" value="N">
                    <spring:message code="tm.report.search.none" text="DEBUG: None" />
                    <input type="radio" name="notes" id="notes" value="ignore">
                    <spring:message code="tm.report.search.ignore" text="DEBUG: Ignore" />
```